# Are there applications for the inverse of the arc length of $ax^n$ and $a^x$? “Closed forms” found.

Tags: exponential-function, special-functions, inverse, arc-length, experimental-mathematics

Based on:

> [How to straighten a parabola?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4209381/how-to-straighten-a-parabola)

and

> [Arc length of $x^n$ found using Hypergeometric function and series. Alternate representations and solution verification needed.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4187181/arc-length-of-xn-found-using-hypergeometric-function-and-series-alternate-re)

Use:

$$\text{ArcLength}(f(x))=\int\sqrt{f’(x)^2+1}dx\\\implies \text{InverseArcLength}(f(x))=\text{inverse function of }\text{ArcLength}(f(x))\\=f^{-1}\left(\pm\sqrt{\left(\frac{d\text{ArcLength}(f(x))}{dx}\right)^2-1}\right)$$
**Inverse of the Arc Length of $ax^n$:**

From the bottom reference using the [Incomplete Beta Function](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=incomplete+beta+function) and the [quantile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_function) [**Inverse Beta Regularized $\text I^{-1}_z(a,b)$**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=inverse+beta+regularized) functions:

$$\text{ArcLength}(ax^n)=\frac{x\sqrt[2n-2]{-a^2n^2x^{2n-2}}\text B_{-a^2n^2x^{2n-2}}\left(\frac1{2n-2},\frac32\right)}{2n-2}\mathop=^{a,x,n>0}\frac{\sqrt[2-2n]{-1}\sqrt[1-n]{an} \text B_{-a^2n^2x^{2n-2}}\left(\frac1{2n-2},\frac32\right)}{2n-2} \implies \boxed{\text{InverseArcLength}(ax^n)\mathop=^{n>1} \frac{\sqrt[2n-2]{\text I^{-1}_{\frac{\sqrt[2n-2]{-1}\sqrt[n-1]{an}(2n-2) x}{\text B\left(\frac1{2n-2},\frac32\right)}}\left(\frac1{2n-2},\frac32\right)}}{\sqrt[2n-2]{-1}\sqrt[n-1]{an}}}$$

[**Test it here**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=+Inversebetaregularized%28%282n-2%29+%28-1%29%5E%281%2F%282n-2%29%29%28an%29%5E%281%2F%28n-1%29%29+x%2F%28beta%281%2F%282n-2%29%2C3%2F2%29%29%2C1%2F%282n-2%29%2C3%2F2%29%5E%281%2F%282n-2%29%29%2F%28%28-1%29%5E%281%2F%282n-2%29%29%28an%29%5E%281%2F%28n-1%29%29%29)

There are a few ways to get around the domain of the function:
If $n$ is a positive irreducible rational number with an even denominator and odd numerator, then, there are no complex number problems. Also, the domain for $n$ can be extended by finding the arc length of $\sqrt[n]x$ by inverting it in terms of $x$.

We cannot find the inverse of the arc length of $x^2$, unless solving for when the arc length equal a complex value, because of the limited domain of $\text I^{-1}_z(a,b)$, but the arc length of $i\,f(x);x,f(x)\in\Bbb R$ should have a similar arc length to $f(x)$. Solve:

$$\text{ArcLength}(ix^2)=\int \sqrt{1-4x^2}dx=\frac12 \sqrt{1-4x^2}+\frac14\sin^{-1}(2x)=-\frac\pi{16}$$

Plug into the boxed formula and use

> [Why does the Dottie Number D$=\sqrt{1-\left(2\text I^{-1}_\frac12(\frac 12,\frac 32)-1\right)^2}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4389528/why-dottie-2-sqrti-1-frac12-frac-12-frac-32-i-1-frac12-frac-12-fr)

$$x=-\frac12\sqrt{\text I^{-1}_\frac12\left(\frac12,\frac32\right)}=-\frac{\sqrt{1-\sqrt{1-\text D^2}}}{2\sqrt 2}$$

to get [**proof**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=-pi%2F16-+integral+sqrt%281-4x%5E2%29+from+0+to+%28-1%2F2sqrt%28%281-sqrt%281-dottie+number%5E2%29%29%2F2%29%29) of the formula:

$$\text{ArcLength}(ix^2)\text{ from }0\text{ to } \frac{\sqrt{1-\sqrt{1-\text D^2}}}{2\sqrt 2} =\int_0^ {\frac{\sqrt{1-\sqrt{1-\text D^2}}}{2\sqrt 2}} \sqrt{1-4x^2}=-\frac\pi{16}$$

**Inverse of the Arc Length of $a^x$:**

Remember that Wolfram Alpha has [**BesselJZero $\text j_{n,k}$**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BesselJZero.html). Both of the following formulas have less restrictions than the above boxed formula. This formula also finds the inverse of the arc length of a logarithmic function :

$$\text{ArcLength}(a^x)=\int \sqrt{\ln^2(a)a^{2x}+1}dx=\frac{\sqrt{\ln^2(a)a^{2x}+1}-\tanh^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\ln^2(a)a^{2x}+1}\right)}{\ln(a)}\implies \boxed{\text{InverseArcLength}(a^x)=\frac{\ln\left(-\frac{\text j^2_{\frac32,\frac{i\ln(a)x}{\pi}}+1}{\ln^2(a)}\right)}{2\ln(a)}}$$

Let $a=-1,x=-2$:

$$\text{ArcLength}((-1)^x)\text{ from }0\text{ to }-\frac{i\ln\left(\frac{1+\text j^2_{\frac32,2}}{\pi^2}\right)}{2\pi}=\int_0^{-0.2890486…i}\sqrt{\pi^2(-1)^{2x+1}+1}dx=-2$$

where $\text j_{\frac32,2}$ is the second smallest solution\fixed point of $\tan(x)=x$

[**for proof of the formula**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=-%28i+%28sqrt%28%CF%80%5E2+%28-1%29%5E%282+x+%2B+1%29+%2B+1%29+-+tanh%5E%28-1%29%28sqrt%28%CF%80%5E2+%28-1%29%5E%282+x+%2B+1%29+%2B+1%29%29%29%29%2F%CF%80%2Cx%3D-%28i+log%28%28%28besseljzero%283%2F2%2C+-%28-2%29%29%29%5E2+%2B+1%29%2F%CF%80%5E2%29%29%2F%282+%CF%80%29)

Using the Inverse Beta Regularized formula:

$$\boxed{\text{InverseArcLength}(a^x)=\lim_{b\to0}\frac{\ln\left(-\frac{\sqrt{\text I^{-1}_{-b\ln(a)x}\left(\frac32,\frac b2\right)-1}}{\ln(a)}\right)}{\ln(a)}}$$

Let $a=-1,x=2i:$

$$\text{ArcLength}((-1)^x)\text{ from }0\text{ to }-\lim_{b\to0}\frac{i\ln\left(\frac{i\sqrt{\text I^{-1}_{2\pi b}\left(\frac32,\frac b2\right)-1}}{\pi}\right)}{\pi}=2i$$

After simplification, we have [**proof**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=-%28i+%28sqrt%281+%2B+%28-1%29%5E%281+%2B+2+x%29+%CF%80%5E2%29+-+tanh%5E%28-1%29%28sqrt%281+%2B+%28-1%29%5E%281+%2B+2+x%29+%CF%80%5E2%29%29%29%29%2F%CF%80%2Cx%3D1%2B2.46205i) for the formula.

Both formulas respectively solve $\text{ArcLength}(a^x)=iy$ or $\text{ArcLength}(a^x)=y$ with $y\in\Bbb R$

**The simple question:**

> Are there any applications for the inverse of the arc length of a power and exponential function?

Some ideas that come to mind are:

- Arc Length Parametrization
- “Straightening” a Curve
- Having “trigonometric function” versions for exponential and power functions like the [Jacobi Elliptic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_elliptic_functions)
- Anything else?

Comment: Does this formula for the arc length of exponent work, by the way? $\int \sqrt{1+a^2 b^2 e^{2bx}}\; dx = \frac{\sqrt{1+a^2 b^2 e^{2bx}}}{b} + \frac{1}{2b} \ln \left(\frac{\sqrt{1+a^2 b^2 e^{2bx}}-1}{\sqrt{1+a^2 b^2 e^{2bx}}+1}\right) + c$ https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2771285/arc-length-of-an-exponential-function

Comment: @Anixx Your formula works for the arc length of $a e^{bx}$ which is just $(e^b)^{x+\frac{\ln(a)}b}$, but shifting the arc length integration bounds by $\frac{\ln(a)}b$  makes the $a$ variable unneeded. Right?